# What is a program I can use to mess up a GNU/Linux system in an automated way?

Tags: administration

I once ran across a program that, when run on a GNU/Linux system, would automatically screw up something about the system. Maybe it would corrupt the users database. Maybe it would mess with the boot files. You wouldn't know. (Obviously, it was supposed to be run in a VM.) Then you (the sysadmin) would have to fix the box for practice.

I've lost the link to this program. Does anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Trouble-Maker](http://trouble-maker.sourceforge.net/).